# How can I execute my except ValueError when I use a letter?

Tags: python

The Except would not execute when I try to use a letter( alphabet)

```
def perform_calculation(number1, number2):
    try:
        result = number1 * number2
        print(f"Result: {result}")
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Invalid input! Please enter an integer.")
# Test case
number1=float(input("Enter the first number:-"))
number2=float(input("Enter the second number:-"))
perform_calculation(number1,number2)
```

Comment: Have you noticed what is the actual error you are getting? Why do you expect `ValueError` to be thrown, and not some other error?

Comment: The ValueError exception will be raised if the call to *float()* fails. You are not catching that

Answer (score 0):

Because your test case contains following lines:

```
number1 = float(input("Enter the first number:-"))
number2 = float(input("Enter the second number:-"))
```

And if you try to use a letter (say `a`) following error will pop up, because of string to float type casting:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'`

In order for your `except` to work (catch undersirable input and show your own error), you can refactor your code like this:

```
def perform_calculation(number_1, number_2):
    try:
        result = float(number_1) * float(number_2)
        print(f"Result: {result}")
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Invalid input! Please enter an integer.")


# Test case
number1 = input("Enter the first number:-")
number2 = input("Enter the second number:-")
perform_calculation(number1, number2)
```

Output:

```
Enter the first number:-a
Enter the second number:-a
Error: Invalid input! Please enter an integer.
```

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is to have a function that robustly acquires a float value. For example:

```
def get_float(prompt: str) -> float:
    while True:
        value = input(prompt)
        try:
            return float(value)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
```

Then your code could be restructured as follows:

```
def perform_calculation(num1: float, num2: float):
    print(f'Result: {num1*num2}')

n1 = get_float('Enter the first number: ')
n2 = get_float('Enter the second number: ')

perform_calculation(n1, n2)
```